# Asp.Net MVC vNext Identity Login route change not working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to set a new route for login, logout, etc.

Right now when I use `app.UseIdentity()` it automatically routes to `/Account/Login`.

When I try to comment out app.UseIdentity though and add

```
MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    defaults: new { controller = "Security", action = "Login" },
    template: "Login/{returnUrl?}")
```

and

```
//app.UseIdentity();

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
    LogoutPath = new PathString("/Logout")
});
```

it doesn't do anything except route to my home page and show a blank page (I assume because it isn't authorized).

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Please show you Startup.cs file.

Comment: I already edited to show the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out by looking through the Asp.Net source:

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/IdentityCookieOptions.cs

```
public static class MyIdentityExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyIdentity(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (app == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        }

        var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Value;

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options.Cookies.ExternalCookie);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options.Cookies.TwoFactorRememberMeCookie);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options.Cookies.TwoFactorUserIdCookie);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"), // REPLACED THIS
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Logout"), // ADDED THIS
            AuthenticationScheme = options.Cookies.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync
            }
        });

        return app;
    }
}
```

And in the `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseMyIdentity()
```